# awk separator preferences

Tags: awk

I write ad hoc awk commands in cygwin to process tab delimited files. Pretty much every command starts with:

```
BEGIN {FS="\t";OFS="\t";ORS="\r\n";}
```

How can I make these separators the default to avoid typing them every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way would be to use a shell alias (add it to `~/.bashrc` or your shell's equivalent):

```
alias awktab="awk -v FS='\t' -v OFS='\t' -v ORS='\t'"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also add a shortcut to it. For example, to have <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> insert `awk -v FS='\t' -v OFS='\t' -v ORS='\t'` into your terminal, add this line to your `~/.inputrc`:

```
Control-G: "awk -v FS='\t' -v OFS='\t' -v ORS='\t'"
```

Then, open a new terminal, type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> and presto!

Answer (score 1):

Since POSIX defines what the [special variables defaults](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/utilities/awk.html#tag_04_06_13_03) are, the simple option is to override them at run-time (the not-simple option being to alter the source).

In the case of `gawk` you can place your common code (typically within `BEGIN {}` blocks) in a library file. If you place these in the default library path (probably `/usr/share/awk/` or `/usr/local/share/awk`), or where the environment variable `AWKPATH` points to, you don't need to use the full path:

```
gawk -f tabfile.awk [...]
```

Unlike other awks, `gawk` allows multiple `-f` options, and allows you to mix both `-f` and program source on the command line.

Recent versions support an additional `-i` include file option (since gawk-4.1.0) and an `@include` directive (since 4.0.x AFAICT) are. This is a slightly more robust and friendly version of `-f`:

```
gawk '@include "tabfile"; /foo/ { ... }'
```

The above will include `tabfile.awk` from `AWKPATH` or default library path. `@include` has been supported for a long time, but via an `igawk` a shell-script wrapper to `gawk`, it's a feature of gawk proper now.

This is compatible with the other two fine answers, e.g.:

```
alias awktab="gawk -i tabfile"
```

There is one subtle different between using this library file approach and using `-v` on the command-line: the command line option takes effect before any awk code is run, so they are set by the time library code is run. This may matter if library code uses such variables (e.g. reading data files).