# Automatically load a user function at startup with awk?

Tags: awk

I guess this answer from [awk separator preferences](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/100866/awk-separator-preferences/101077#101077) already gives a hint, but I thought I'd ask explicitly:

Is there an equivalent to a `.bashrc` file for `awk`, where I could define my own library functions, which would be automatically (pre)loaded at every call to `awk` - and without using `-f` or `@include` at the command line?

Comment: Why not make `awk` into an alias to `awk -f yourfunction` or similar?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @terdon - I simply want to avoid making new aliases, and have a set of commonly used functions be always automatically loaded... And I don't want to alias `awk` itself, because then I may eventually forget it has been aliased `:)` - and making up extra alias names is extra cognitive load... I guess I'm too used to the concept of "automatically load startup script" from e.g. `bash` ... Cheers!

Comment: GNU awk has `-i --include` option which you probably want. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28463193/7015849).

Answer (score 3):

I believe that what you're asking for is impossible and I have 2 pieces of evidence for this:

1) The `awk(1)` man page doesn't have a `FILES` section that lists any files related to the operation of `awk`. Contrast that, for example, with the `bash(1)` man page that lists all of Bash's initialization files in a separate `FILES` section. Most commands whose behavior can be modified by configuration files, will name these files in their man page(s).

2) The `ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES` section in the `awk(1)` man page also doesn't mention any environment variables related to the loading of external files except for `GAWK_PATH` in the case of `gawk`, which tells it where to look for files named with the `-f` option.

I know this evidence isn't exactly conclusive, but barring any counterexamples, I'd say there's a very high chance you won't be able to accomplish this without using `-f` and/or aliasing `awk` as terdon suggested.